# Spring - @RequestMapping for empty servlet path is not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.2 Web MVC with default annotation mapping. I use a servlet mapping like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>profil</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>de.kicktipp.web.config.servlets.ProfilServletConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>profil</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/info/profil/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is our servlet configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("de.kicktipp.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
public class ProfilServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors ( InterceptorRegistry registry )
    {
       // we add a few interceptors here
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator viewNameTranslator ( )
    {
        DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator defaultRequestToViewNameTranslator = new DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator();
        defaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.setStripExtension(false);
        defaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.setAlwaysUseFullPath(false);
        defaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.setPrefix("profil/");
        return defaultRequestToViewNameTranslator;
    }
}
```

The wildcard matching is important because we want to match many urls with this pattern like `/info/profil/page1`, `/info/profil/page2` and so on.

When I  want to match the "base" URL `/info/profil` without a trailing slash it is picked up by the servlet "profil".

Now I have tried three controller methods to match `/info/profil` with a handler method:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
protected void get1 () {}

@RequestMapping("")
protected void get2 () {}

@RequestMapping("/info/profil")
protected void get3 () {}
```

Only the last one works. This is because UrlPathHelper#getLookupPathForRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) returns the full path within application if the path within the servlet is an empty string:

```
public String getLookupPathForRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Always use full path within current servlet context?
    if (this.alwaysUseFullPath) {
        return getPathWithinApplication(request);
    }
    // Else, use path within current servlet mapping if applicable
    String rest = getPathWithinServletMapping(request);
    if (!"".equals(rest)) {
        return rest;
    }
    else {
        return getPathWithinApplication(request);
    }
}
```

For the request to "/info/profil/" the method will return "/", but for "/info/profil" (without trailing slash) it will return "/info/profil" because the rest variable is empty string and teherfore the method returns the pathWithinApplication.

Other paths are usually matched against the path inside the servlet mapping (as alwaysUseFullPath defaults to false). But the "root" path is matched against the full path inside the application (like it always does when alwaysUseFullPath is true).

Why is it like this? Why is spring not trying match the empty string but instead tries to match the path within the application?

See spring issue here https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10491

Comment: That's why you put a URL mapping of `/` for your `DispatcherServlet` and let it delegate to your controllers.

Comment: are you using latest 3.2.2 or 3.2.0 or other version of Spring 3.2 like 3.2.0M1  or 3.2.rc1 etc?  I have similar code using Spring 3.2.2 and it works correctly. One differrence is I am using Context from xml file and enabled `MVC:annotation-Driven`

Comment: I use 3.2.2. How can it work if UrlPathHelper is not returning empty string? Maybe you test it with a trailing slash.

Answer (score 3):

try adding

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list() {
        return "redirect:/strategy/list";
    }`

the result:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/strategy")
    public class StrategyController {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StrategyController.class);

    @Autowired
    private StrategyService strategyService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list() {
        return "redirect:/strategy/list";
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listOfStrategies(Model model) {
        logger.info("IN: Strategy/list-GET");

        List<Strategy> strategies = strategyService.getStrategies();
        model.addAttribute("strategies", strategies);

        // if there was an error in /add, we do not want to overwrite
        // the existing strategy object containing the errors.
        if (!model.containsAttribute("strategy")) {
            logger.info("Adding Strategy object to model");
            Strategy strategy = new Strategy();
            model.addAttribute("strategy", strategy);
        }
        return "strategy-list";
    }
```

** credits:

[Advanced @RequestMapping tricks – Controller root and URI Template](http://duckranger.com/2012/04/advanced-requestmapping-tricks-controller-root-and-uri-templates/)

and

[CRUD tutorial by dtr-trading.blogspot.it](http://dtr-trading.blogspot.it/)

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]**

As I see you're using annotation mvc config. The default mapping is configured to "/" path in your application. To change these default settings, you can edit your web.xml to this template:

```
<web-app>
  <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
       instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
       fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
       specified for component-scanning -->
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>de.kicktipp.controller.ProfilAppConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
           instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
           and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>de.kicktipp.controller.ProfilServletConfig</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <!-- map all requests for /info/profil/* to the dispatcher servlet -->
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/info/profil/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

So, you have the `de.kicktipp.controller.ProfilServletConfig` on your application. Just check if the first code block for `de.kicktipp.controller.ProfilAppConfig` (contextClass) is really necessary.

Source: [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-instantiating-container-web)

Comment: this is not helpful as "/info/profil" does not match other urls like "/info/profil/page". I updated my question to reflect the need of mapping all subpaths.

Comment: I didn't see the you're using annotation config for Spring. So, I edit the question to configuration for annotation support. Please check if is helpful.

Comment: This is still not helpful. Maybe I don't understand you, but my web.xml is properly sending the request to /info/profil to the right dispatcher servlet. It is just that my requestmappingHandlerMapping is not picking up the @RequestMapping because of UrlPathHelper.

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to explain something else, got it. what is the value for `String rest`for each case?

Comment: I added a paragraph under the last code block for clarification